# Website Drag-able Horizontally on Ipad - (No Horizontal Scroll Bar Visible)

Tags: php, css, wordpress, ipad, safari

While using an safari on ipad the website loads and the user can drag the website to the left and right which ends up showing a beige background (even though there is no horizontal scroll bar visible) Video below shows the issue.

[Video Showing the Issue](https://www.icloud.com/attachment/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fcvws.icloud-content.com%2FB%2FAa22gDxIVeZOuNuVqTdq7S9D4AZzAZj64Zhx_a5L9OgSHkCpE7Szzv_u%2F%24%7Bf%7D%3Fo%3DAkMSZqKFx5EvwWqiUNf5mdnmtw0k4sQH3-gXM_2_oFM2%26v%3D1%26x%3D3%26a%3DBTHHQB6zBRGtA1z4OAEA_wHIAP97lGge%26e%3D1486319741%26k%3D%24%7Buk%7D%26fl%3D%26r%3DE2697C71-87BF-43C6-AFE1-C39030444D05-1%26ckc%3Dcom.apple.largeattachment%26ckz%3DA4B54CCD-28E9-4E81-8CEF-2EFD73FAAB3E%26p%3D18%26s%3DbxaG_hcUsPUuNuKM1LIdiV2zJlk&uk=nhq-LMCaNzLq3SOzHOMr9Q&f=IMG_1883.MOV&sz=27096346)

I have added this to the wordpress header.php file but still the same;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a safari feature that indicates the end of scrollable page. You can change that colour by setting the background colour of the lowest level container, most likely the body tag

Comment: So do you mean, it is possible to do that with every website viewed on Safari only when using ipad?

Comment: Not only the iPad, it's the same for the Macs too. IDK about iPhone safari and the windows version of safari. But it should be same for iPhones too as it's iOS

Answer (score 0):

The third column div, within the website header was overflowing the body towards the right, so even though; a horizontal scroll bar was not visible (disabled using overflow:hidden and viewport meta) it was still allowing the left and right horizontal drag-ability for the user, when viewing on iPad (only ipad).

Using chrome inspector and setting the borders to: solid 3px; helps in finding the overflowing area.